# One Way Sync and skip specific folder in Linux

Tags: linux, synchronization, iteration, rsync

I have a folder "Source" with the following structure

```
Source
----Folder1
        ----Subfolder1
----Folder2
        ----subfolder2
        ----private
----Folder3
        -----subfolder4
                     ----subsubfolder4
        -----private
```

I am writing a linux bash file to move any file found in those sub directories to a new destination folder "Destination" and create the folder tree if it is not created in the destination.

So far my code is doing the job and is reserving the directory tree in both folders and deleting the source file once copied

```
cd /Source/
find * -iname "*.*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' /usr/bin/rsync -avR --remove-source-files "{}" /Destination/
```

My problem is that I dont want the code to copy any file located in any folder named "private" or create the private folder itself in the "Destination". I just want to skip the folder private whenever it comes across it.

Any idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync <options> --exclude private` to skip all occurences of the folder "private" and its contents.